# Inflating a layout that contains a nested layout definition for a custom widget

Tags: android

I'm trying to refactor a convoluted view by consolidating it's layouts into a single file.

Currently I have a `DialogFragment`, **`CustomViewDialog`**, which is simply a `LinearLayout` of a `TextView`, for the title, and a **`CustomView`**.

**CustomViewDialog.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/dialog" >  

  <TextView android:id="@+id/dialog_title_tv"/>   

  <!--CustomView (added from code) -->

</LinearLayout>
```

**CustomView.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CustomView android:id="@+id/custom_view">  
    <ListView android:id="@+id/custom_view_lv" />   
</CustomView>
```

**`CustomViewDialog`**'s `OnCreateView()` inflates it's layout and adds a constructed **CustomView** to it.

```
public class CustomViewDialog : DialogFragment
{
    View _thisView;
    CustomView _customView;

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        _thisView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CustomViewDialog, container, false);    
        _customView = new CustomView(_thisView.Context);            
        _thisView.AddView(_customView);
    }
}
```

**`CustomView`**'s constructor in turn inflates it's layout and initializes it's view.

```
public class CustomView : LinearLayout
{
    View _thisView;

    public CustomView( Context context ) : base(context) 
    { 
        _thisView = _inflater.Inflate( Resource.Layout.CustomView, this, true );    
    }
}
```

---

**I'm trying to combine the two layout files like so**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/dialog" >

  <TextView android:id="@+id/dialog_title"/>

  <!--CustomView (defined within xml -->  
  <CustomView android:id="@+id/custom_view">      
    <ListView android:id="@+id/custom_view_list_lv" />      
  </CustomView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The classes were slightly modified to accommodate this change as follows

```
public class CustomViewDialog : DialogFragment
{
    View _thisView;
    CustomView _customView;

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        _thisView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CustomViewDialog, container, false);    
        //_customView = new CustomView(_thisView.Context);          
        //_thisView.AddView(_customView);
    }
}
```

**`CustomView`** is now inflated in **`CustomViewDialog`**, so I tried assigning `_thisView` to `this`, but that isn't working as expected.

```
public class CustomView : LinearLayout
{
    View _thisView;

    //public CustomView( Context context ) : base(context) 
    public CustomView(Context context, IAttributeSet attributes) : base(context, attributes)
    { 
        //_thisView = _inflater.Inflate( Resource.Layout.CustomView, this, true );  
        // DOESN'T WORK
        _thisView = this;
        _thisView = ((Activity)context).Window.DecorView.FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content);
    }
}
```

**I'm not sure of the best way to get a reference to the already constructed view in** **`CustomView`**'s **constructor.** **`CustomView`** no longer has it's own layout file to inflate.

Because the `context` here is a `ContextThemeWrapper` (from the Dialog),  `Window` (`getWindow()`) isn't available. `getWindow()` is an `Activity` method only (which incidentally is a direct descendant of `ContextThemeWrapper`).

---

**Update (10/19/2017)**

Found a helpful comment in `Fragment` source ([**xref**](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Fragment.java))

```
/**
* @hide Hack so that DialogFragment can make its Dialog before creating
* its views, and the view construction can use the dialog's context for
* inflation.  Maybe this should become a public API. Note sure.
*/
public LayoutInflater getLayoutInflater(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final LayoutInflater result = mHost.onGetLayoutInflater();
    if (mHost.onUseFragmentManagerInflaterFactory()) {
        getChildFragmentManager(); // Init if needed; use raw implementation below.
        result.setPrivateFactory(mChildFragmentManager.getLayoutInflaterFactory());
        }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if **layouts** are, or meant to be, utilized by individual **Views**, as they are in **Activitys** (which are aggregates of views). I'm not sure if this is true for all built-ins, so need to verify the source. A `TextView` takes an **attribute set** and works with that, and doesn't inflate a layout for itself. Although I've done just this when defining custom views, it seems kinda abusive.

Comment: When a custom view/widget's layout definition is nested within another layout, inflation becomes inconsistent b/c the nested view now relies on the containing view that is itself in the midst of construction. There is no inflated view to call `findViewById()` on in order to initialize it's components (from `CustomView(Context context, IAttributeSet attributes)` anyways).

Comment: All the logic from `CustomView` would have to be moved into `CustomViewDialog` in order to properly inflate the nested layout, costing modularity (maybe someday it becomes a full screen view).

Answer (score 0):

Modifying **`CustomView`**'s layout so that it contains the "body" and then leaving just the "stub" in **`CustomViewDialog`**'s layout gives:

**CustomViewDialog.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/dialog" >

  <TextView android:id="@+id/dialog_title"/>

  <!--CustomView "stub" (body defined within xml) -->
  <CustomView android:id="@+id/custom_view"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**CustomView.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--CustomView "body" -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/custom_view_list_lv" />
```

**`CustomViewDialog`**'s `onCreateView` is the same as in the second option from above

```
public class CustomViewDialog : DialogFragment
{
    View _thisView;
    CustomView _customView;

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        _thisView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CustomViewDialog, container, false);    
        //_customView = new CustomView(_thisView.Context);          
        //_thisView.AddView(_customView);
    }
}
```

**`CustomView`**'s constructor now inflates it's (modified) layout as usual.

```
public class CustomView : LinearLayout
{
    View _thisView;

    //public CustomView( Context context ) : base(context) 
    public CustomView(Context context, IAttributeSet attributes) : base(context, attributes)
    { 
        _thisView = _inflater.Inflate( Resource.Layout.CustomView, this, true );    
    }
}
```